# How to do rounding in math/big float?

Tags: go

I have a `big.Float`, in the golang standard `math/big` library, and I want to *round* it into the nearest `big.Int`. I don't know how.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    bfloat, _ := (&big.Float{}).SetString("1.8")

    // what to do here to round bfloat to nearest int?
    bint, _ := bfloat.Int(nil) // not this, this truncates

    fmt.Println(bint.String())
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may [add](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.Add) `0.5` to it before calling [`Float.Int()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.Int), and you get what you want.

At least for positive numbers. If the number is negative, you have to add `-0.5` so e.g. `-0.6` gets "rounded" to `-1.0`.

This is how you can do that:

```
delta := 0.5
if bf.Sign() < 0 {
    delta = -0.5
}
bf.Add(bf, new(big.Float).SetFloat64(delta))
bint, _ := bf.Int(nil)
```

You may simplify this addition like this if you want to:

```
bf.Add(bf, new(big.Float).SetFloat64(0.5*float64(bf.Sign())))
```

Let's test it for some values:

```
for _, s := range []string{"-0.8", "-0.3", "0.6", "1.1", "1.8"} {
    bf, _ := (&big.Float{}).SetString(s)

    delta := 0.5
    if bf.Sign() < 0 {
        delta = -0.5
    }
    bf.Add(bf, new(big.Float).SetFloat64(delta))
    bint, _ := bf.Int(nil)

    fmt.Printf("%5s => %2s\n", s, bint)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/azkSO2h97pl)):

```
 -0.8 => -1
 -0.3 =>  0
  0.6 =>  1
  1.1 =>  1
  1.8 =>  2
```

Comment: SetPrec just sets the byte to 1, so it does this - https://play.golang.org/p/3rCapyy1Jcx - not what I want here

Comment: @KarelBílek Ops, you're right, removing that alternative.